# configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.48.0

Tags: python, macos

I've been trying to install Exempi by following [this](https://python-xmp-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) method.

Running`./configure` yields `configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.48.0`

I presume I have a successful installation of boost using the method specified [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

Are there any workarounds for this error?
I'm using a MacBook Air running on macOS Big Sur, I'm also trying to avoid using MacPorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring Exempi by `./configure BOOST_ROOT=/path/to/your/boost/root/` (change to your Boost path).

By default Exempi searches for boost in default system paths if BOOST_ROOT is not provided, otherwise inside BOOST_ROOT directory.

Alternatively, in MacOS, you can install Boost by `brew install boost`, then you don't need `BOOST_ROOT` in configure, because brew installs boost to default locations.

In Linux you may install Boost through `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev`.

Comment: I tried using `brew install boost` and it worked!

Comment: @Luke Ah, sorry, you have macos. Yes, for macos brew install will do the thing instead of my suggested apt install. I'll correct my answer now to change to macos variant.